# Visual Studio 2022 17.1 upgrade causes authenticated nuget restore failure

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

Our .NET framework builds started failing after upgrading to VS2022 17.1.1 on Windows 10 (previously 17.0.6)

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Password decryption is not supported on .NET Core for this platform. The following feed uses an encrypted password: '<our repository>'. You can use a clear text password as a workaround.
```

The error is nuget password related yet we can run `nuget restore` commands fine.

It fails against our self hosted nuget repository that is password protected even though all our packages are already restored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to remove and re-add the nuget repository with a clear text password

```
dotnet nuget remove source <repository-name>
dotnet nuget add source "https://<repository-url>/nuget" --name "<repository-name>" --password iloveponies --store-password-in-clear-text --username mylittlepony
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error, but the most inner exception in the stack trace was: Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) is not supported on this platform.

And due to update to new version, for me it looks like known issue: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/23498#issuecomment-1046937978